# Pass form field to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to pass specific form field from form into modal, with my code I managed to pass the whole form, but cant  achive to target only specific elements.
**1)** Pass only spefic field from form.
 2)In my code you can see that im replacing some css class with new one, and i need to check with IF , are they exist or not.
3) and if someone can explain to me $.ajax -how to force the cache to false.
 
4) Also i have 2 button trigers, if you click on first i want to show let's say 1,2,3,4 fields, and if you click on second button you get 3,4,5,6 fields, i know that i can write two sepparate js, but it would be better to hear from you what is best option to achive this.
This is mine js script for now:

```js
function onclick_modal() {
 var modalcreate = '<div id="fast-modal">';
  modalcreate += '<div id="fastmodal-contain">';
   modalcreate += '<div id="modal-data"></div>';
  modalcreate += '</div>';
 modalcreate += '</div>';
 var $html_modal = $(modalcreate);
 $('body').append($html_modal);
 
 $html_modal.on('click', function(e){ if($(e.target).attr('id')=="fast-modal") { $(this).remove(); } });
 
 $.ajax({
   url: "https://linkwhereformis",
 }).done(function(data) {
  var $htmldata = $($(data).find('#formid')[0].outerHTML);
  $htmldata.find('.dontneedthis').parent().remove();
  $htmldata.find( "div" ).removeClass().addClass('grid-tablet-12-12 grid-desktop-12-12');
  $htmldata.find( "div ul li span" ).removeClass().addClass('grid-tablet-12-12 grid-desktop-12-12 lajna');
  $htmldata.find( "div ul li div" ).removeClass().addClass('grid-tablet-5-7 grid-desktop-6-8');
  $htmldata.find('.buttons').html('<button type="submit" class="modalnibutton" data-step="5" id="confirm-form-submit modalbutton">Submit</button>');
  $html_modal.find('#modal-data').html( $htmldata );
  
 });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modallink').click(function(e) {  
e.preventDefault();
      onclick_modal();
    });
 
 $('#modallink2').click(function(e) {  
e.preventDefault();
      onclick_modal();
    });
});
```

```css
.modalnibutton{
float: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.88);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-left: 27px;
    padding-right: 27px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#fast-modal{
position: fixed; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 z-index: 9997;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
 overflow-y: scroll; 
 overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 #fastmodal-contain {
 width: 700px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff; min-height: 100px; margin-top: 50px;
 }
 
 #modal-data{
 float: left; background: #fff; width: 100%; padding: 15px 0px;
 }
 

#modalbutton {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="" style="zoom: 1;" id="modallink">
     SUBMIT LINK 1   </a>
          
          <BR><BR>
          <a href="#" title="" style="zoom: 1;" id="modallink2">
     SUBMIT LINK 2   </a>
```